# Entire Section using slds-section with the toggle is clickable

Tags: lightning-web-components, css, slds

When I click on anywhere over the section of slds-section, the toggle turns on/off.

```
 <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap">
                      <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-medium-size_12-of-12 slds-large-size_12-of-12 slds-p-horizontal_medium">
                        <span>
                              <div class="slds-section slds-form-element__control">
                                <h4 class="slds-page-header slds-p-vertical_xx-small">
                                  <label class="slds-checkbox_toggle slds-grid">
                                    <span class="slds-truncate slds-p-top_xx-small" title="Section Title">Check Toggle</span>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-toggle-18" value="checkbox-toggle-18" aria-describedby="checkbox-toggle-18" checked={isToggleActive} onclick={checkIsToggleActive}/>
                                    <span id="checkbox-toggle-8" class="slds-checkbox_faux_container slds-p-horizontal_small" aria-live="assertive">
                                      <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span>
                                      <span class="slds-checkbox_on"></span>
                                      <span class="slds-checkbox_off"></span>
                                    </span>
                                  </label>
                                  
                                </h4>
                              </div>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

How to restrict the toggle turn on/off to the toggle itself and not the entire section?[image: When I click anywhere on the section the toggle is turned on/off. I want the user to click on the toggle only to turn it on/off and not the entire section]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the `slds-section`, it's the [`<label>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) and that's the default HTML behavior:

> Associating a `<label>` with a form control, such as `<input>` or `<textarea>` offers some major advantages:
>
> - When a user clicks or touches/taps a label, the browser passes the focus to its associated input (the resulting event is also raised for the input). That increased hit area for focusing the input provides an advantage to anyone trying to activate it — including those using a touch-screen device.

Indeed if you set a background color to the label just to highlight it, you can check that clicking on the section outside the label doesn't trigger the toggle.

Therefore the way to fix this behavior is to let the label get just the minimum width needed by its content:

```html
<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-m-top_medium">
    <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-1 slds-p-horizontal_medium">
        <span>
            <div class="slds-section slds-form-element__control">
                <h4 class="slds-page-header slds-p-vertical_xx-small slds-grid"> <!-- added slds-grid -->
                    <label class="slds-checkbox_toggle slds-grid" style="width:auto;"> <!-- added width:auto -->
                        <span class="slds-truncate slds-p-top_xx-small" title="Section Title">Check Toggle</span>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-toggle-18" value="checkbox-toggle-18" aria-describedby="checkbox-toggle-18" checked={isToggleActive} onclick={checkIsToggleActive}/>
                        <span class="slds-checkbox_faux_container slds-p-horizontal_small" aria-live="assertive">
                            <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span>
                            <span class="slds-checkbox_on"></span>
                            <span class="slds-checkbox_off"></span>
                        </span>
                    </label>
                </h4>
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

By the way, I removed `slds-medium-size_12-of-12 slds-large-size_12-of-12` since they were superfluous: you already have `slds-size_1-of-1` which means `width: 100%`, so there is no need to set again `width: 100%` if it's a tablet (slds-medium) or a desktop (slds-large).
I removed the `id` attribute too. [Docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-components-dom-work.html)

> the IDs that you define in HTML templates may be transformed into globally unique values when the template is rendered. If you use an ID selector in JavaScript, it won’t match the transformed ID